# Why does my regex (jobboardid=0#5) produce no data in Google Analytics?

Tags: regex

I am attempting to create a Goal in Google Analytics to track when someone successfully applies for a job in our Recruitment Web App.

The below is the final part of the URL for the 'Thank you for applying' page.

/application?c=merlin&jobboardid=0#5

I have tried regular expression: (jobboardid=0#5) but it returns no data

I have also tried escaping some of the characters e.g. (jobboardid\=0#5)

Regular expression: (jobboardid) does return data, but not the data relating to step 5, submit, in the application process.

I expect (jobboardid=0#5) to produce data for Google Analytics like (jobboardid) is producing data.

[Code with results 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjajj.png)

[Code with no results 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbLvW.png)

Kind regards,
Lewis

Comment: Please add the code you tried, and it's results.   Also please look at formatting (see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Consider using `(.*)` to make sure the text you're matching against really contains what you say. In particular I wouldn't be surprised if the `=` and `#` were urlencoded into `%3D` and `%23`

Comment: Hi I have added screenshots of the code I have tried - screenshot 1 is as far as I can get before the code stops working, as seen in screenshot 2

Comment: Are you sure the `#` is even making it into Google Analytics? The `#` ("hash") is used for navigation *within a page* (technically, called "anchoring"). It would not surprise me if the `#` and anything after it was stripped off before going into Google Analytics unless you very explicitly passed that information to it via the API.

Comment: Hi Ed, that's a good theory - if the # ("hash") is not making it into Google Analytics then the problem is not with the Regex but with the website itself.